# How to skip the current iteration of tf.while_loop()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have only recently started working with Tensorflow2. I'm trying to re-program a script that randomly cuts squares out of images. The original code comes from this github repository: [Link](https://github.com/zhunzhong07/Random-Erasing/blob/master/transforms.py). I fail due to the tf.while_for() loop in Tensorflow2. But here is the code I wrote so far:

```py
def random_erasing(img, probability = 0.5, sl = 0.02, sh = 0.4, r1 = 0.3):
    '''
    img is a 3-D variable (ex: tf.Variable(image, validate_shape=False) ) and  HWC order

    probability: The probability that the operation will be performed.
    sl: min erasing area
    sh: max erasing area
    r1: min aspect ratio
    mean: erasing value
    '''

    i = tf.constant(0)
    N = tf.constant(100)
    while_condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, N)

    def body(i):

        def calculate_valid_boxes(h, w):

            h_tmp = tf.Variable(tf.shape(img)[1]-h, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
            w_tmp = tf.Variable(tf.shape(img)[2]-w, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)

            # x1 = random.randint(0, img.size()[1] - h)
            # y1 = random.randint(0, img.size()[2] - w)
            x1 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=x, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32), h_tmp)
            y1 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=x, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32), w_tmp)

            return x1, y1


        area = tf.shape(img)[1] * tf.shape(img)[2]

        target_area = tf.random.uniform([3], minval=sl, maxval=sh, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64) * tf.cast(area, tf.dtypes.float64)
        aspect_ratio = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform([3], minval=r1, maxval=1/r1), tf.dtypes.float64)

        h = tf.cast(tf.math.round(tf.sqrt(target_area * aspect_ratio)), tf.dtypes.int32)
        w = tf.cast(tf.math.round(tf.sqrt(target_area / aspect_ratio)), tf.dtypes.int32)

        # if condition: w < img.size()[2] and h < img.size()[1]:
        cond_1 = tf.less(w, tf.shape(img)[2])
        cond_2 = tf.less(h,tf.shape(img)[1])
        x1 = tf.cond(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(cond_1, cond_2), tf.int32) == 3, lambda: calculate_valid_boxes(h, w))

        return h, w, x1, y1


    # mask_size= area of cutout, offset= place of cutout, constant_value=pixel value to fill in at cutout
    image = tfa.image.cutout(img, mask_size=(h, w), offset=(x1, y1), constant_values=255)

    return image
```

My problem lies in the following line:

```py
x1 = tf.cond(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(cond_1, cond_2), tf.int32) == 3, calculate_valid_boxes(h, w))
```

I always get "Exception has occurred: TypeError cond(): false_fn argument required" messages. I want to call the function "calculate_valid_boxes()" in this line if the statement is true or if the statement is false I want to jump to a new iteration.

In plain Python you could solve this either with "break" or "continue" statement (depending on the implementation) but with Tensorflow2 I'm not able to find a solution.

If the information is relevant, the function works with a batch of images.

Comment: I thought in Tensorflow 2 you can use pythonic loops and it will be automatically converted to tf.while_loop? so why you don't just use normal python loops and then you can use break or continue?

Comment: When I followed this approach, I also encountered errors that were similar. I don't have the exception anymore but it was something like: result of if and else branch must have the same data form. Furthermore, the code cannot be debugged correctly using the annotation @tf.function. This makes my life as a Tensorflow2 beginner much more difficult.

Comment: What about doing:

`x1 = tf.cond(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(cond_1, cond_2), tf.int32) == 3, calculate_valid_boxes(h, w), lambda: x1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in the code, you shouldn't use `tf.Variable` objects for this, those `tf.map_fn` are avoidable and `tf.cond` must always have two branches. Here is a possible implementation of the code you linked in TensorFlow, adapted to work on batches of images. Each image in the batch is independently modified with the given probability on a different box. I broken down the logic in several functions for clarity.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def random_erasing(img, probability=0.5, sl=0.02, sh=0.4, r1=0.3, mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465]):
    '''
    img is a 4-D variable (ex: tf.Variable(image, validate_shape=False) ) and NHWC order

    probability: The probability that the operation will be performed.
    sl: min erasing area
    sh: max erasing area
    r1: min aspect ratio
    mean: erasing value
    '''
    return tf.where(tf.random.uniform([tf.shape(img)[0], 1, 1, 1]) > probability,
                    img,
                    _do_random_erasing(img, sl, sh, r1, mean))

def _do_random_erasing(img, sl, sh, r1, mean):
    s = tf.shape(img, out_type=tf.int32)
    # Sample random h and w values
    def sample_hw(h, w):
        s = tf.shape(img)
        area = s[1] * s[2]
        target_area = tf.random.uniform([s[0]], sl, sh)
        target_area *= tf.dtypes.cast(area, target_area.dtype)
        aspect_ratio = tf.random.uniform([s[0]], r1, 1 / r1)
        h_new = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.round(tf.math.sqrt(target_area * aspect_ratio)), tf.int32)
        w_new = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.round(tf.math.sqrt(target_area / aspect_ratio)), tf.int32)
        # Only replace values that are still wrong
        m = (h >= s[0]) | (w >= s[1])
        h = tf.where(m, h_new, h)
        w = tf.where(m, w_new, w)
        return h, w
    # Loop
    _, h, w = tf.while_loop(
        # While there are iterations to go and h and w are not good
        lambda i, h, w: (i < 100) & tf.reduce_any((h >= s[1]) | (w >= s[2])),
        # Get new h and w values
        lambda i, h, w: (i + 1, *sample_hw(h, w)),
        [0, tf.fill([s[0]], s[1]), tf.fill([s[0]], s[2])])
    # Erase box if we got valid h and w values
    return tf.cond(tf.reduce_all((h < s[1]) & (w < s[2])),
                   lambda: _erase_random_box(img, h, w, mean),
                   lambda: img)

def _erase_random_box(img, h, w, mean):
    # Make box boundaries
    s = tf.shape(img, out_type=tf.int32)
    # Add extra dimensions for later
    h = tf.reshape(h, [-1, 1, 1])
    w = tf.reshape(w, [-1, 1, 1])
    # Sample random boundaries
    h_max = tf.dtypes.cast(s[1] - h + 1, tf.float32)
    x1 = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(h)) * h_max, h.dtype)
    w_max = tf.dtypes.cast(s[2] - w + 1, tf.float32)
    y1 = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(w)) * w_max, w.dtype)
    # Replacement mask
    _, ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(s[0]), tf.range(s[1]), tf.range(s[2]), indexing='ij')
    mask = (ii >= x1) & (ii < x1 + h) & (jj >= y1) & (jj < y1 + w)
    # Replace box
    result = tf.where(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1),
                      tf.dtypes.cast(mean, img.dtype),
                      img)
    # Maybe can use tfa.image.cutout for this function?
    return result

# Test
tf.random.set_seed(100)
# Example batch of three 10x8 single-channel random images
img = tf.random.uniform([3, 8, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
# Apply erasing
erased = random_erasing(img, probability=0.5, sl=0.02, sh=0.4, r1=0.3, mean=[-1])
# Check results
with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
    erased_np = erased.numpy()
    print(erased_np[0, :, :, 0])
    # [[ 0.25  0.48  0.39  0.82  0.24  0.39  0.96  0.74  0.31  0.78]
    #  [ 0.36  0.44  0.39  0.41 -1.   -1.   -1.    0.99  0.08  0.7 ]
    #  [ 0.3   0.69  0.95  0.65 -1.   -1.   -1.    0.37  0.5   0.66]
    #  [ 0.42  0.64  0.71  0.86 -1.   -1.   -1.    0.78  0.16  0.19]
    #  [ 0.47  0.66  0.97  0.63 -1.   -1.   -1.    0.66  0.41  0.18]
    #  [ 0.56  0.33  0.58  0.03 -1.   -1.   -1.    0.01  0.44  0.29]
    #  [ 0.77  0.63  0.61  0.09  0.77  0.25  0.15  0.18  0.75  0.6 ]
    #  [ 0.74  0.4   0.15  0.18  0.18  0.07  0.53  0.16  0.61  0.42]]
    print(erased_np[1, :, :, 0])
    # [[0.55 0.31 0.67 0.42 0.93 0.31 0.1  0.67 0.11 0.3 ]
    #  [0.99 0.66 0.57 0.51 0.01 0.76 0.69 0.28 0.1  0.6 ]
    #  [0.91 0.63 0.23 0.   0.21 0.7  0.85 0.16 0.35 0.18]
    #  [0.67 0.83 0.66 0.4  0.51 0.84 0.07 0.62 0.8  0.66]
    #  [0.62 0.23 0.29 0.99 0.9  0.7  0.68 0.09 0.92 0.67]
    #  [0.36 0.75 0.51 0.76 0.68 0.56 0.07 0.68 0.57 0.58]
    #  [0.98 0.75 0.22 0.87 0.28 0.55 0.77 0.65 0.8  0.28]
    #  [0.76 0.46 0.11 0.85 0.3  0.35 0.81 0.48 0.24 0.81]]
    print(erased_np[2, :, :, 0])
    # [[ 0.42  0.33  0.44  0.68  0.89  0.88  0.8   0.72  0.5   0.61]
    #  [ 0.54 -1.   -1.   -1.   -1.    0.56  0.33  0.24  0.98  0.89]
    #  [ 0.06 -1.   -1.   -1.   -1.    0.64  0.76  0.26  0.1   0.57]
    #  [ 0.39 -1.   -1.   -1.   -1.    0.09  0.24  0.47  0.92  0.2 ]
    #  [ 0.46 -1.   -1.   -1.   -1.    0.61  0.11  0.5   0.52  0.06]
    #  [ 0.71  0.74  0.03  0.77  0.87  0.51  0.42  0.87  0.73  0.01]
    #  [ 0.18  0.71  0.38  0.17  0.18  0.56  0.58  0.7   0.1   0.87]
    #  [ 0.46  0.19  0.98  0.19  0.19  0.41  0.95  0.    0.82  0.05]]
```

One caveat with this function is that the `tf.while_loop` tries to find good `h` and `w` values for *all* images in the batch, but if it fails to sample a good pair of values in the 100 loop iterations even for just one of the images, then if will not apply the erasing to *any* image. You might tweak the code in one way or another to work around that, although I suppose just giving a reasonable number of iterations should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will check my code again and read about the errors you mentioned. The code that works, thanks for that. The only problem I'm currently seeing is that the deleted areas are only square. 
Also I am still looking for the possibility to change the color of the deleted areas.

Comment: @john-mueller There was a bug in the code that was causing the square-only regions, it works properly now making random rectangles. About the color replacement, what the code does is it replaces the randomly selected area with the value given in `mean`, which can have as many channels as the image (this is the same as the code you linked), although you can change that logic to do whatever you want.

Comment: My record consists of images and bounding boxes. I have not yet succeeded in overlaying the images with the generated mask and deleting all bounding boxes overlaid by the deleted parts.

Is there a possibility to realize this?

Comment: @john-mueller I'm not fully following. You want to "discard" bounding boxes that intersect (completely or partially?) with the "erased" region? For that, it may be easier to operate with the erased region coordinates (`(x1, x1 + h, y1, y1+ w)`). If you have trouble with it maybe you can either edit the question or post a new one with details about the format of input data and expected output...

Comment: you have understood it exactly. with a Threshold it should be determined how high the IOU may be. Everything that is greater than the threshold should be removed from the bounding boxes. 
I am still trying to do this and if it does not work I will create a new question